# Using Steganography to hide image inside image

Tags: java, steganography

I am trying a program to hide an image inside image by replacing the LSB of RGB components of the target image by MSB of the secret image which I have found here https://towardsdatascience.com/steganography-hiding-an-image-inside-another-77ca66b2acb1
I am trying to do it in java. The hidden image appears be hidden well inside the target image but while retrieved image seems to have messes up the pixels.

Code for hiding image

```
for(int y=0 ; y<orHeight ; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0 ; x<orWidth ; x++)
        {
            //RData[],GData[],BData[] are storing the red, green and blue component respectively for ecach pixel of target image which is then being converted to 8 bit binary string.     
            RHString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(RData[n]);
            RData[n]= Integer.parseInt(RHString[n]);
            RHString[n] = String.format("%08d",RData[n]);
            
            
            GHString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(GData[n]);
            GData[n]= Integer.parseInt(GHString[n]);
            GHString[n] = String.format("%08d",GData[n]);
            
            
            BHString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(BData[n]);
            BData[n]= Integer.parseInt(BHString[n]);
            BHString[n] = String.format("%08d",BData[n]);
            
    //oRData[],oGData[],oBData[] are storing the red, green and blue component respectively for ecach pixel of image to be hidden.      
            ROString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(oRData[n]);
            oRData[n]= Integer.parseInt(ROString[n]);
            ROString[n] = String.format("%08d",oRData[n]);
            
            
            GOString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(oGData[n]);
            oGData[n]= Integer.parseInt(GOString[n]);
            GOString[n] = String.format("%08d",oGData[n]);
            
            
            BOString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(oBData[n]);
            oBData[n]= Integer.parseInt(BOString[n]);
            BOString[n] = String.format("%08d",oBData[n]);
            
            
            
            
            RHString[n] = RHString[n].substring(0,4)+ROString[n].substring(0,4);
            GHString[n] = GHString[n].substring(0,4)+GOString[n].substring(0,4);
            BHString[n] = BHString[n].substring(0,4)+BOString[n].substring(0,4);
            //converting binary string to decimal integer using Integer.parseInt() 
            RData[n]= Integer.parseInt(RHString[n],2);
            GData[n]= Integer.parseInt(GHString[n],2);
            BData[n]= Integer.parseInt(BHString[n],2);
            
            
            n++;

            

            
        }
    }
    
            n=0;
    for(int y=0 ; y<orHeight ; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0 ; x<orWidth ; x++) {
        
            Color newC = new Color(RData[n], GData[n],BData[n]);
            orImage.setRGB(x,y,newC.getRGB());
            
            
            Color c = new Color(orImage.getRGB(x,y), true);// Color class will return the colour of that pixel specified by x,y coordinates
            
            
            n++;
        }
    }
```

Code for retrieving image(it is a separate code that takes in input as the image that is created in the previous code )

```
    int n = 0;
    for(int y=0 ; y<hiHeight ; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0 ; x<hiWidth ; x++)
        {
            
            RHString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(RData[n]);
            RData[n]= Integer.parseInt(RHString[n]);
            RHString[n] = String.format("%08d",RData[n]);
            
            
            GHString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(GData[n]);
            GData[n]= Integer.parseInt(GHString[n]);
            GHString[n] = String.format("%08d",GData[n]);
            
            
            BHString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(BData[n]);
            BData[n]= Integer.parseInt(BHString[n]);
            BHString[n] = String.format("%08d",BData[n]);
            
            
                            
            RHString[n] = RHString[n].substring(4,8)+"0000";
            GHString[n] = GHString[n].substring(4,8)+"0000";
            BHString[n] = BHString[n].substring(4,8)+"0000";
            
            //converting binary string to decimal integer using Integer.parseInt() 
            RData[n]= Integer.parseInt(RHString[n],2);
            GData[n]= Integer.parseInt(GHString[n],2);
            BData[n]= Integer.parseInt(BHString[n],2);
            n++
        }
    }
    
    n=0;
    for(int y=0 ; y<hiHeight ; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0 ; x<hiWidth ; x++) {
        
            Color newC = new Color(RData[n], GData[n],BData[n]);
            hidImage.setRGB(x,y,newC.getRGB());
            n++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you don't increment `n` in the first loop of your retrieval code, but I don't see how that would result in the image you get. (I would expect the rest of the image would just remain the same as before you retrieved the hidden image.) Also, I would strongly recommend using Java's bitwise operators instead of manipulating strings like this.

Comment: The format change worked for me. Changed it to PNG and the output was as expected. Thanks all for help.